# Credit Card dirt

Tags: cleaning

How can I clean the smudge off from my credit card chip? I have not used anything on it as of yet.  I tried to use the card at a Walmart and it errored out. I discovered a smudge on half the chip and would like to wipe it clean without damaging the information.  I thought about rubbing alcohol on a q-tip but am not sure it won't damage the chip.

Comment: You can also tell your credit card company that your card's chip is damaged, and ask them to send you a replacement card. I'm not sure if it will have the same number or not; credit card companies may change the # as a security measure.

Answer (score 3):

Alcohol swab or cotton swab that is alcohol soaked will work fine, just be sure to dry it after.

Comment: If you are using either of those, definitely a good idea to ensure it isn't soaking wet, just damp. Most pre-packaged alcohol swabs aren't too wet. But if you're doing your own with a cotton swab, make sure it isn't super soaking/dripping wet.

Answer (score 3):

the classic way to clean electrical contacts is by gently rubbing the contact pads with a soft pencil eraser. Don't press too hard or you'll remove the gold plating, which is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, these things are tough enough that you can clean it with a pan scrubber and soapy water and it won't come to any harm, but try something like a cloth wetted with soapy water first.

If they were fragile, they wouldn't be used - you don't need to treat them like a precious ornament

Comment: Not only are they robust but they are easy and free to replace.